# Why is this showing to multiple decimal places?

Tags: php

Why is this not keeping the rounding on the `$artWidthCM` and `$artHeightCM` when I am adding it to the object?

If I echo out the values I get what is expected: '0.305'.

But when adding it to `$artObj` it prints as '0.304999999999999993338661852249060757458209991455078125'.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    $artObj = new stdClass();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        //Dimensions
        $dimenionsStrip = str_replace(' ', '', $row["Dimensions"]);
        $dimensionsArr = explode("x", $dimenionsStrip);
        $artWidthInch = 12;  // $dimensionsArr[0];
        $artHeightInch = 12;  // $dimensionsArr[1];

        $artWidthCM = (round(($artWidthInch * 2.54) * 2) / 2) / 100;
        $artHeightCM = (round(($artHeightInch * 2.54) * 2) / 2) / 100;

        // Build Object
        $artObj->id = $row["ArtID"];
        $artObj->artwidth = $artWidthCM;
        $artObj->artheight = $artHeightCM;
    }

    $artJSON = json_encode($artObj, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    echo '['.$artJSON.']';

} else {
    echo "No Artwork Found";
}
```

Prints JSON as follows:

```
[{ "id": "35628", "artwidth": 0.304999999999999993338661852249060757458209991455078125, "artheight": 0.304999999999999993338661852249060757458209991455078125 }]
```

On my local machine with exact same code it prints as:

```
[{ "id": "35628", "artwidth": 0.305, "artheight": 0.305 }]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: It depends on your processor architecture, your OS and the position of stars.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of floating point precision. See the Warning at https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Highlight from the link:

> So never trust floating number results to the last digit, and do not
>   compare floating point numbers directly for equality. If higher
>   precision is necessary, the arbitrary precision math functions and gmp
>   functions are available.

The floating point handling may be different on different machines, that's  why it behaves "correctly" on one and "incorrectly" on other.

Comment: I think his question is more about why `echo` is automatically rounding this value while `json_encode` is not. Obviously, the floating point value can never really be trusted. However, it shouldn't change from statement to statement.

Comment: Or why it's getting rounded when printed from the terminal but not as a json response, perhaps.

Comment: I understand that the question is about different behaviour on different systems. I added it to the answer.

Comment: I had assumed that this was all being done on the same machine, probably my mistake.